# Using jQuery replace to find multiple text strings

Tags: jquery

I'm using replace to locate a text string (three letters of the month plus a subsequent space to avoid what's in the A tag) and then remove it, however I'm looking to replicate this across each month of the year. There's two different classes in play as well, depending on whether the month you're in is the current one. I'm unsure on how to chain replace together.

```html
<tr>
  <td class="EventListCalendarItemDefault">
    <a class="yearViewHeader" href="">January</a><br>
    Jan 01 <a href="">Location</a><br>
    Jan 08 <a href="">Location</a><br>
    Jan 15 <a href="">Location</a><br>
    Jan 22 <a href="">Location</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="EventListCalendarItemSelected">
    <a class="yearViewHeader" href="">February</a><br>
    Feb 04 <a href="" title="">Location</a><br>
    Feb 11 <a href="" title="">Location</a><br>
    Feb 18 <a href="" title="">Location</a><br>
    Feb 25 <a href="" title="">Location</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
      var t = $('.EventListCalendarItemDefault').html();
      var r = t.replace(new RegExp('Jan ', 'gi'), '');
      $('.EventListCalendarItemDefault').html(r);  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to include both selectors in the jQuery object. Then you can provide a function to `html()` which accepts the current HTML value as an argument and returns the new value. Finally, you can use the pipe character (`|`) as an 'OR' operation within the regex to replace multiple values. Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.EventListCalendarItemDefault, .EventListCalendarItemSelected').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(new RegExp('(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ', 'gi'), '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="EventListCalendarItemDefault">
      <a class="yearViewHeader" href="">January</a><br> Jan 01 <a href="">Location</a><br> Jan 08 <a href="">Location</a><br> Jan 15 <a href="">Location</a><br> Jan 22 <a href="">Location</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="EventListCalendarItemSelected">
      <a class="yearViewHeader" href="">February</a><br> Feb 04 <a href="" title="">Location</a><br> Feb 11 <a href="" title="">Location</a><br> Feb 18 <a href="" title="">Location</a><br> Feb 25 <a href="" title="">Location</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.EventListCalendarItemDefault, .EventListCalendarItemSelected').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/[a-z]{3}\s/gi, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="EventListCalendarItemDefault">
      <a class="yearViewHeader" href="">January</a><br> Jan 01 <a href="">Location</a><br> Jan 08 <a href="">Location</a><br> Jan 15 <a href="">Location</a><br> Jan 22 <a href="">Location</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="EventListCalendarItemSelected">
      <a class="yearViewHeader" href="">February</a><br> Feb 04 <a href="" title="">Location</a><br> Feb 11 <a href="" title="">Location</a><br> Feb 18 <a href="" title="">Location</a><br> Feb 25 <a href="" title="">Location</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```